# Convert QByteArray to vector of quint32

Tags: qt, qbytearray

I am reading a `QByteArray` from binary file and need to convert it to a `QVector<quint32>`. I have tried the following code:

```
QVector<quint32> qByteArrayToQuint32Vector(const QByteArray bytes, QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder) {
   QByteArray temp;
   QVector<quint32> convertedData;
   QDataStream stream(&temp, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

   for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i++) {
       stream << bytes[i];
   }

   stream.setByteOrder(byteOrder);
   quint32 t = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i += 4) {
       stream >> t;
       convertedData.push_back(t);
   }

   return convertedData;
}
```

It does not work, and the converted data is just zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I've misunderstood the use of `QDataStream`. The working solution is below:

```
QVector<quint32> qByteArrayToQuint32Vector(const QByteArray bytes, QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder) {

    int byteArraySize = bytes.length();
    int vectorLen = byteArraySize/4;

    QVector<quint32> convertedData;
    convertedData.resize(vectorLen);

    QDataStream in(bytes);
    in.setByteOrder(byteOrder);

    for (int i = 0; i < vectorLen; i++) {
        in >> convertedData[i];
    }

    return convertedData;
}
```